# Appending Textbox value to Summernote Textarea using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor, summernote

Im new on using Summernote Textarea , and Im having difficulties on passing the value on a summernote textarea. Tried using the conventional `.html(), .text() and .val()` to pass the value of my dropdown and append it inside the textarea. Here is my set of codes

```
 $("#btnAddVariable").click(function (e) {
                var eVariable = $("#EmailVariable option:selected").val();
                $("#EmailMessage").val(eVariable);
                $("#EmailMessage").text(eVariable);
                alert(eVariable);
            })
```

My Dropdown

```
<div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailVariable, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmailVariable, new SelectList(ViewBag.emailVariables, "Value", "Text"), "Please Select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                   @* @Html.DropDownList(model => model.EmailVariable, new SelectList(ViewBag.emailSender, "Value", "Text"), "Please Select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="button" id="btnAddVariable" value="Add Variable" class="btn btn-primary chosen" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

and my Summernote Textarea

```
<div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailMessage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <div class="ibox-content no-padding">
                                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.EmailMessage, new { @class = "summernote", rows = "5", cols = "90" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Hoping someone can help me with this. Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: can you post RENDERED html, ie: copy a sample from browser inspector

Comment: @Scaramouche Ok I will provide Wait for a while

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
 $("#btnAddVariable").click(function (e) {
       var eVariable = $("#EmailVariable option:selected").val();
       $("#EmailMessage").val(eVariable);                    
       $(".summernote").summernote('code',eVariable); //add text to summernote
       alert(eVariable);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

$("textarea.note-codable").val(eVariable);

Comment: sir still not working ,unable to target the <p> inside the note-codable

Comment: You can access it using $("textarea.note-codable p")

Comment: is there a chance that i can use .append it with summernote class? their website seems down as of the moment

Comment: use addClass('summernote') method